# Sharepoint CAML query to search folder on ID field

Tags: sharepoint, caml

Using CAML in WSS3, I am trying to search for a folder by the folder ID field. This results in 'undefined' when searching the 'Folder' content type but works fine searching for a regular item.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value type='Integer'>"+folderIDtoFind+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query>
...
<QueryOptions><ViewAttributes Scope='Recursive' /></QueryOptions>
```

Any suggestions for how I can find folders by their id's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value type='Counter'>"+folderIDtoFind+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query>
```

Also, grab a copy of [A CAML builder tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420835/u2u-caml-query-builder-no-longer-available)...

Comment: Wow that was an easy one! Switching Integer to Counter did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: U2U has taken down CAML Builder.  See this question for options still available:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420835/u2u-caml-query-builder-no-longer-available

Comment: I had a problem with type='Counter', it has to be uppercase: Type='Counter'