# U2U Caml Query Builder no longer available?

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I'm trying to download the fantastic U2U Caml Query Builder but all the links I'm finding are dead and I can't find any references to it on the u2u site. Has it been end-of-lifed? Does anyone know of a location where it is still available from?

Dead link - http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx

new link: http://www.u2u.be/Software

Comment: Mark, check this link from U2U: http://www.u2u.be/Software

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/72165/16880

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the renewed website, we waited until the CAML Query Builder was upgraded to SharePoint 2013 to put it online.
New version at:

http://www.u2u.be/Software

Comment: I keep getting a `unhandled exception error` everytime I pick a column from the list.

Answer (score 13):

U2U Caml Query Builder seems to have been removed from their renewed Site, but there are still working alternatives to this tool:

[Stramit Caml Viewer](http://spcamlviewer.codeplex.com/)

[SharePoint CAML Query Helper](http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/)

[Caml Designer for SP 2010 and SP 2013](http://sharepoint.biwug.be/SitePages/Caml_Designer.aspx)

[CAML Generator](http://www.CAMLGenerator.com/)

Update:
The new version from U2U is available:
[U2U CAML Query Builder 2013](http://www.u2u.be/Software)

Answer (score 9):

I Googled the filename (CamlBuilderSetupv4.0.0.0.zip) and found this result. You only need the .msi file:

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1H-kV-5gwStUlF1OEdjWWJZNXc

Comment: this setup does not work with message: 
Method 'get_SiteUrl' in type 'U2U.SharePoint.CAML.Client.ClientSite' from assembly 'U2U.SharePoint.CAML.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=21d512c8d1f0645f' does not have an implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tool I wrote.
You can download the source or use it here: http://www.CAMLGenerator.com/

Answer (score 0):

it's now available on the Belgian Information workers user group site:
http://www.biwug.be/resources