# PHP form into SharePoint 2010

Tags: php, xml, sharepoint-2010, drupal-7

The idea sounds simple: to submit data entered into a PHP form (we use Drupal 7) into SharePoint 2010. But I'm having some issues figuring it out.

Each form entry should be recorded in SharePoint as an item, so that it can searched for and differentiated between. So I believe a SharePoint list or form library would work. I am just lacking to experience with SharePoint to really know where to start with this.

I'd like to know how you believe this could work, if at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect to Sharepoint Database through PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782645/connect-to-sharepoint-database-through-php)

Comment: I'm afraid not hakre, that is the other way around. I don't need to query SharePoint's database. Please remove the downvote and duplicate.

Comment: This website requires that you tell that earlier. Show which of the existing Q&A didn't work for you and explain exactly why. And in your question, not just in comments because someone else did search around a little. Especially as the Q&A given talks about two-way access so there is no other way around unless you mean that you don't want to interact with sharepoint at all ;) - And I never downvoted, albeit your question deserves alone a close because you ask for a tool or resource which is considered off topic. Just saying.

Comment: I understand that this seems like I'm trying to query SharePoint. But for the type of person who will be able to answer this, those with SharePoint experience, they will understand my question as intended and see it is not a duplicate. It would require no further explanation to them. Therefore I feel the question is adequate and not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could certainly work, you would need a list created in sharepoint with the necessary columns to store your form data. Then from your PHP code you can call the lists web service `http://<site>/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx` and you would add items using the `UpdateListItems` method.

Have a look at the MSDN docs [Lists Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists%28v=office.14%29.aspx), [Lists.UpdateListItems Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists.updatelistitems%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and [How to: Update List Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms440289%28v=office.14%29.aspx), these don't use PHP but you should be able to adapt the examples.

When querying the lists you will need to use CAML to write the queries for the list web service see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420835/u2u-caml-query-builder-no-longer-available) for some tools that will help writing these. These queries are wrapped in the `SOAP` envelope that you send to the web service.

I don't know PHP but the quote and code below came from [David's IT Blog - Creating SharePoint list items with PHP](http://davidsit.wordpress.com/2010/03/03/creating-sharepoint-list-items-with-php/)

> To get the code to work, you'll need the NuSOAP library, your own local Lists WSDL file,  and of course your own personalized authentication/list variables in the code below. This code has been tested with SharePoint Online and PHP 5.3, but should work with MOSS 2007.

```php
<?php

// Requires the NuSOAP library
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

$username = 'yourUsername';
$password = 'yourPassword';
$rowLimit = '150';

/* A string that contains either the display name or the GUID for the list.
 * It is recommended that you use the GUID, which must be surrounded by curly
 * braces ({}).
 */
$listName = "TempList";

/*
 * Example field (aka columns) names and values, that will be used in the
 * CAML query. The values are the attributes of a single list item here.
 * If the field name contains a space in SharePoint, replace it
 * here with _x0020_ (including underscores).
 */
$field1Name = "Title";
$field2Name = "Address";
$field3Name = "Premium_x0020_customer";

$field1Value = "John Smith";
$field2Value = "USA";
$field3Value = "1";

/* Local path to the Lists.asmx WSDL file (localhost). You must first download
 * it manually from your SharePoint site (which should be available at
 * yoursharepointsite.com/subsite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL)
 */
$wsdl = "http://localhost/phpsp/Lists.wsdl";

//Basic authentication is normally used when using a local copy a the WSDL. Using UTF-8 to allow special characters.
$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl, true);
$client->setCredentials($username,$password);
$client->soap_defencoding='UTF-8';

//CAML query (request), add extra Fields as necessary
$xml ="
 <UpdateListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>
 <listName>$listName</listName>
 <updates>
 <Batch ListVersion='1' OnError='Continue'>
 <Method Cmd='New' ID='1'>
 <Field Name='$field1Name'>$field1Value</Field>
 <Field Name='$field2Name'>$field2Value</Field>
 <Field Name='$field3Name'>$field3Value</Field>
 </Method>
 </Batch>
 </updates>
 </UpdateListItems>
";

//Invoke the Web Service
$result = $client->call('UpdateListItems', $xml);

//Error check
if(isset($fault)) {
 echo("<h2>Error</h2>". $fault);
}

//extracting the XML data from the SOAP response
$responseContent = utf8_decode(htmlspecialchars(substr($client->response,strpos($client->response, "<"),strlen($client->response)-1), ENT_QUOTES));

echo "<h2>Request</h2><pre>" . utf8_decode(htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES)) . "</pre>";
echo "<h2>Response header</h2><pre>" . utf8_decode(htmlspecialchars(substr($client->response,0,strpos($client->response, "<")))) . "</pre>";
echo "<h2>Response content</h2><pre>".$responseContent."</pre>";

//Debugging info:
//echo("<h2>Debug</h2><pre>" . htmlspecialchars($client->debug_str, ENT_QUOTES) . "</pre>");
unset($client);
?>
```